# DBT CLI Selector – Run tests for a specific column on a specific model

Tags: dbt

I have a DBT model with many tests. I want to run tests for only 1 specific column. How can I do that from the CLI?

**Example model:**

```yaml
my_table.yml 


models:
  - name: my_table
    columns:
      - name: col_1
        tests:
          - unique
          - accepted_values:
            values:
              - 1
              - 2
      - name: col_2
        tests:
          - not_null
          - accepted_values:
            values:
              - 3
              - 4
```

**Selector I can use to run only `not_null` tests:**

```bash
dbt test -s my_table,test_name:not_null
```

**What I want (which isn't supported, I don't think) – a selector that will run all tests for `col_1` only:**

```bash
dbt test -s my_table,column_name:col_1
```

Answer (score 1):

When using dbt, selecting a specific column directly with the `select` attribute isn't supported. Instead, you must reference a resource from a defined set: models, sources, seeds, snapshots, or tests.

To test a single column, you can create a [custom singular test](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/tests#singular-tests).

A singular test operates in a straightforward manner: if you can formulate a SQL query that identifies failing rows, you can save that query within a .sql file in your test directory. This saved query becomes a test, executed using the `dbt test` command.

To define a singular test, create a file named `my_col_1_null_test.sql` in your test folder (by default it is the `tests` folder) with the following content:

```py
# you can put any custom logic
SELECT * FROM {{ref('my_table')}} WHERE col_1 IS NULL
```

This SQL query selects all records where `col_1` is null. The test fails if any records are fetched matching this criterion.

Execute the test using `dbt test --select my_col_1_null_test`.

For further details, refer to the [documentation on test selection examples](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/test-selection-examples) and [singular tests](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/tests#singular-tests).

Answer (score 0):

how about this :

```
dbt test --models my_table --select col_1
```

Comment: Does not work for me, sadly... I get the error `The selection criterion '<col>' does not match any nodes`